# css style content attribute

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list where I use counter in content.

### Question:

How can I change color to content attribute ( NUMBERS ) only ( e.g. 1.2, 1.3, ... to red ) ?

*Note: Looking for **CSS only** ( no HTML change ! )*

### HTML:

```
<ol>
        <li>Item
            <ol>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item
                    <ol>
                        <li>Item</li>
                        <li>Item</li>
                        <li>Item</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>Item</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ol>
```

### CSS:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")". ";
    counter-increment: item
}
```

### Wanted output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it for all of the numbers, just add `color:red;` to your css for the numbers like this

```
ol li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")". ";
    counter-increment: item;
    color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZSkLE/3/

To to do it for the lower levels (which is what it looked like you wanted to do before editing your question) you could do this..

```
ol li ol li:before {
    color:red;
}
```

and to stop the next level being red..

```
ol li ol li ol li:before {
    color:black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZSkLE/1/